# Prove that a bounded sequence contains all of it's accumulation points

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Homework question:

Let {$x_n$} be a bounded sequence. Prove that the set of all subsequential limits of {$x_n$} is closed.

Any help would be appreciated.

(I edited this so that anyone who looks at this in the future will not get confused by my incorrect interpretation of the question. It now matches the second part of the solution, instead of both the second and the first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement that if $(x_n)$ is bounded then $(x_n)$ contains all its accumulation points is false.

Take for example $x_n=1/n$. This is bounded, but zero is an accumulation point which is not part of the sequence.

---

If you ask to prove that the set of limit points is closed, this is true. If $y_n$ is a sequence of limit points which converges to $y$, then there exist terms $x_n$ in the sequence such that $|x_n-y_n|<1/n$. As a consequence
$$ |x_n-y|\leq |x_n-y_n|+|y_n-y| \to 0$$ so $x_n$ converges to $y$ which makes $y$ a limit point.

Comment: Ah, the language of the question was ambiguous, and I took the wrong path on the ambiguity. It said to prove that "the set of all the subsequential limits is closed, i.e., _it_ contains all of its accumulation points, and I thought by _it_ the question meant {xn}.

Thanks, I would have been stumbling on that for a while.